# Setting modifier using xmodmap

Tags: linux, xorg, xmodmap, devuan

I am using GNU/Linux (Devuan) with the mate desktop and with i3wm.
I would like to assign `mod1` to `Meta_L`. If I show the current assignment with

```
$ xmodmap
```

I get

```
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
```

So I tried the following:

```
$ xmodmap -e "clear mod1"
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):
...
mod1
```

and then

```
$ xmodmap -e "add mod1 = Meta_L"
$ xmodmap
...
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
```

So, I am getting the old assignment back.

I am not sure what is happening. Am I doing something wrong or is `xmodmap` or some other program ignoring / overriding my assignment?